# How to use a resolved target entity in a Symfony2 form type?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There is <kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/ShoppingCart/Order.php</kbd> which resolve <kbd>OrderInterface</kbd> and it works fine with Doctrine.

If try use it in form `'class' => OrderInterface::class`  then I got an error:

`Class "ShoppingCartBundle\Entity\OrderInterface" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?"`

Of course it is possible define `'class' => Order::class` directly, but in that case loses advantages of resolve target entities configs.

<kbd>src/ComplaintsBundle/Form/Type/ComplaintType.php</kbd>

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
        ->add('order', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'required'    => true,
                'class'       => OrderInterface::class,
                'property'    => 'id',
            )
        );
}
...
```

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
    resolve_target_entities:
        ShoppingCartBundle\Entity\OrderInterface: AppBundle\Entity\ShoppingCart\Order
```

Answer (score 1):

Real class name is resolved during metadata loading.
To get real class name by interface metadata loading should be triggered.
This may be achieved with next code

```
$entityManager = $managerRegistry->getManager();
$metadata = $entityManager->getClassMetadata(OrderInterface::class);
$realClassName = $metadata->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `doctrine.dbal.connection.event_manager` in your form as `evm` and `EntityManager` as `em`.

After that you could try something like this:

```
private function resolveClass(string $className): string
{
    $eventArgs = new OnClassMetadataNotFoundEventArgs($className, $this->em);
    $this->evm->dispatchEvent(Events::onClassMetadataNotFound, $eventArgs);

    $metadata = $eventArgs->getFoundMetadata();
    if ($metadata === null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Failed to resolve class $className");
    }

    return $metadata->getName();
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
        ->add('order', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'required'    => true,
                'class'       => $this->resolveClass(OrderInterface::class),
                'property'    => 'id',
            )
        );
}
```

I didn't actually test this, just looked at [how Doctrine does this](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php#L106).

Comment: thanks for answer, unfortunately it not works for me, probably due to doctrine version used in project `"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5"`

Comment: What exactly version do you have? You can check out with `composer show`.
Why it's not working?

Comment: doctrine v2.4.8. It's not working because in this version there is no class `OnClassMetadataNotFoundEventArgs` also no `Events::onClassMetadataNotFound`

Comment: I'm looking at Doctrine 2.4 code and my best guess would be to use

Comment: The way it works in Doctrine 2.4, the resolver is actually bound to particular associations, you'd need to resolve particular association, not an entity. You can see example of it in this test https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/v2.4.8/tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Tools/ResolveTargetEntityListenerTest.php#L56-L61